# Error while compiling c program using gcc <filename.c> thru the CLI

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, g++

Whenever I try to compile a c program thru CLI using `gcc <filename.c>`, I get the error:

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Also, `sudo apt-get install gcc` says it's already there.

Comment: Get the output of `gcc --version` and `g++ --version`. I guess having different versions of `gcc` and `g++` is the issue here

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929308/trilinos-c-error-trying-to-exec-cc1plus-execvp-no-such-file-or-director) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Just installing the `gcc` package is not enough; the package `build-essential` will give you everything you need to compile C.

Answer (score 0):

Gcc tries to call the C++ compilier. Do you have the C++ compiler g++ already installed?

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```